# Notification trampoline restriction - open activity in lock screen without unlocking

Tags: android, android-12

[Similar questions 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687434/notification-open-different-activities-dynamically-on-android-12-trampoline-r)

[Similar question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69238026/android-12-notification-trampoline-restrictions)

**TL;DR:** Answers to [How to perform notification-action (click) on lock-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724567/how-to-perform-notification-action-click-on-lock-screen) don't work anymore cuz now you can't `startActivity()` from services or broadcast receivers. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

**DETAILS**

I have an app that must open an activity on top of the lock screen.
Before targeting Android 12, I could just add an action button to the notification:

```
val intent = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags)
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
builder.addAction(drawable, buttonText, pendingIntent)
```

`pendingIntent.getBroadcast()` worked great on the notification action button, because the broadcast will be fired even if the device is unlocked.

The `NotificationReceiver` class would then get the broadcast WITHOUT unlocking the phone, and it would open the activity on top of the lock screen from there.

Android 12 introduced [Notification Trampoline restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines), now we cannot call `startActivity()` from broadcast receivers or services. I could use `pendingIntent.getActivity` instead of `pendingIntent.getBroadcast` and launch the Activity directly, but the problem is that `getActivity` isn't triggered until AFTER the phone is unlocked (you click on the notification action button > it requests to unlock device > once unlocked, it starts the activity)

Any idea on how to open an activity from a notification without unlocking your phone targeting Android 12+?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, I have something similar. Im my app I have an alarm which should open the alarm activity when alarm triggered. What I did to solve this problem:

**1) Use full screen intents:**

When you configure your notification, just add this line to tell that you are going to use full screen intent:

```
val pendingIntent = //Pending intent of the activity to launch
.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent)
```

**2) Use flag on your activity:**

To tell the system that your activity is going to appear above the lock screen, in your `onCreate()` before you call super set this flags:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Tested on Android 12. Activity is launching