# Visibility of image button not working for lollipop devices and above

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` that is by default `invisible` :

```
  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/anchor"
    android:src="@drawable/anchor"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_row_progress_bar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

On the activity I change It's attribute with this code :

```
 if(lastPotition == 1){
    mImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 } else{
    mImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```

The problem is that in pre lollipop the Image Button works fine but in APIs 21 and 22 doesn't work

This is the declaration of the `ImageButton`:

```
private ImageButton mImageButton;
mImageButton =(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.anchor); //anchor
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to verify that you set correct visibility to `imageButton`?

Comment: Eventually i have found the problem , because i don't have lollipop device i use emulator and the checking of visibility is inside a if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) so because i have a mouse and i use the scroll button of the mouse the scroll state doesn' t working but if i scroll my list view with the mouse like touching the screen it's working

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but later i have discovered that this is related to the settings in a lollipop device.

Here are the three options described here:
**[Lollipop Notification setVisibility() Does Not Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932457/lollipop-notification-setvisibility-does-not-work/26933303#26933303)**

- Show all notification content makes all notifications (regardless of
  visibility) effectively public.
- Hide sensitive notification content respects the new visibility
  types.
- Don't show notifications at all will make all notifications
  effectively secret.